# What is the difference between = and := in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, operators, colon-equals

What is the difference in between

```
set test_var = 20;
```

and

```
set test_var:=20;
```

as they both seem to **assign the value** ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Both of them are **assignment operators** but one thing I can find their differences is that `=` can be used to perform boolean operation while `:=` cannot.

**valid**: SUM(val = 0)
Invalid: SUM(val := 0)

[FROM User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html)

One more thing, *You can also assign a value to a user variable in statements other than SET. In this case, the assignment operator must be := and not = because the latter is treated as the comparison operator = in non-SET statements.*

```
mysql> SET @t1=1, @t2=2, @t3:=4;
mysql> SELECT @t1, @t2, @t3, @t4 := @t1+@t2+@t3;
+------+------+------+--------------------+
| @t1  | @t2  | @t3  | @t4 := @t1+@t2+@t3 |
+------+------+------+--------------------+
|    1 |    2 |    4 |                  7 | 
+------+------+------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 18):

It's more or less Syntactic sugar.

Take a look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/assignment-operators.html)

Most important difference is

> Unlike =, the := operator is never interpreted as a comparison
>   operator. This means you can use := in any valid SQL statement (not
>   just in SET statements) to assign a value to a variable.

Answer (score 3):

You can only use := for assignment - never for comparison. It's just a bit of syntactic sugar, it doesn't really change the functionality at all. You'll see it a lot in generated SQL from code.

Comment: Dang, everyone beats me to it. Hah.

Answer (score 1):

Using `:=` in a `SET` and `SELECT` statement is interpreted as assignment.

Using `=` in a `SET` statement is interpreted as assignment.

However,
Using `=` in a `SELECT` statement is interpreted as a bool operator (comparison).

So if you mean assignment, it is always safe to use `:=`