# why we can use = and := both with set?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

Generally we know that `'='` operator using for comparison and `':='` for assignment,

But while using with `SET` both are working as `assignment operator` why?

below `stored procedure` 
for example:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `substringExample`()
BEGIN 
    DECLARE x varchar(7);    
    DECLARE num int;
    DECLARE inc int;

    SET inc:= 1;

    WHILE inc<1400 DO

    SELECT SUBSTRING(USER_TEMP_NUM, 8, 13) AS ExtractString 
    INTO x FROM USER_REGISTRATION_DETAILS where sl_no=inc;

    SET num= CONVERT(x,int);

    IF (num%2=0) THEN
        SELECT num;
    END IF;
       SET inc:=inc+1;
    END WHILE;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

in the above code  `SET num= CONVERT(x,int);` gives the correct output as well as  `SET num:= CONVERT(x,int);`

I am beginner of stored procedure so dont know at expert level

Comment: `:=` operator is mainly used for assignment operations inside queries. Inside a query you cannot use `=` because this is reserved for comparisons. If you want to use `SET` in a separate statement, i.e. not in the context of a query, then you are free to use either of the operators.

Comment: Read the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/assignment-operators.html

Comment: thanks @GiorgosBetsos for your response , can you share me any document or link for this so i can get depth knowledge about it

Comment: Thank you @P.Salmon

Answer (score 0):

From [John Woo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15614225/3876565)'s answer:

Both of them are assignment operators but one thing I can find their differences is that = can be used to perform boolean operation while := cannot.

```
valid: SUM(val = 0)
Invalid: SUM(val := 0)
```

[FROM User-Defined Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html)

One more thing, You can also assign a value to a user variable in statements other than SET. In this case, the assignment operator must be := and not = because the latter is treated as the comparison operator = in non-SET statements.

```
mysql> SET @t1=1, @t2=2, @t3:=4;
mysql> SELECT @t1, @t2, @t3, @t4 := @t1+@t2+@t3;
+------+------+------+--------------------+
| @t1  | @t2  | @t3  | @t4 := @t1+@t2+@t3 |
+------+------+------+--------------------+
|    1 |    2 |    4 |                  7 | 
+------+------+------+--------------------+
```

And also check this link, hope it helps you,

[What is the difference between := and = mysql assignment operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20515450/what-is-the-difference-between-and-mysql-assignment-operator)